# Heat transfer confusion

Tags: thermodynamics

suppose two objects are at 0 degree celcius

if they are heated uptil both temperature reach  20 degree celcius

so their specific heat capacity is different,so they will absorb different amount of heat but their temperature would be same,

so in this case if both the objects are in contact ,will heat exchange happen,because both have same same temperature so they should not,but both have different heat energy levels so heat moves from higher energy potential to lower potential level//

Comment: Heat is a form of energy, and temperature is a measure of how concentrated that energy is.  The driving force for heat transfer is a temperature difference, regardless of how much "heat content" each object has.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @DavidWhite You are making it sound like temperature is a measure of how concentrated heat is and that an object can "contain" heat, whereas both are internal energy not heat. I don't mean to be critical, but I just feel we need to do all we can to not promulgate the confusion between heat and internal energy.

Comment: @BobD, I take the chemical engineering viewpoint, where the standard state is an ideal gas at zero K, and enthalpy is measured against that standard state.  From that viewpoint, objects have a heat content, which is different than heat transfer.  In other words, there is more than one way to view such problems as this.

Comment: @DavidWhite Just to be clear, are you saying that heat can be a state property?

Comment: @BobD, no.  I'm trying to point out that "heat" is not "hot", as the English language tends to create some ambiguities that are difficult to unlearn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so in this case if both the objects are in contact , will heat exchange
> happen

No.

Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. If there is no temperature difference between objects there can be no energy transfer in the form of heat.

> but both have different heat energy levels so heat moves from higher
> energy potential to lower potential level

Heat does not move from a higher energy object to a lower energy object. Heat moves from a higher temperature object to a lower temperature object. The temperature of an object does not equal the energy of an object. Temperature is a measure of the average translational kinetic energy of the molecules of an object. The total molecular kinetic energy of the object is the average per molecule times the total number of molecules (mass of the object).

Don't think of the heat capacity of an object as a measure of how much heat is "contained" in an object. Objects don't contain heat. They contain internal energy. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference.

The heat capacity of an object determines, all other things being equal, how much the temperature of an object will change as a result of heat transfer. It also determines how much energy is available to transfer in the form of heat. The heat capacity of an object equals the specific heat of the material of the object times its mass.

As an example, suppose we have two objects A and B made of the same material (same specific heat $c$), but object B has ten times the mass of object A, meaning it has ten times the heat capacity of A.

Let the initial temperatures be $T_{A}=200 C$ and $T_{B}=100 C$.  We place the objects in contact with one another and isolate them from everything else. Since $T_{A}>T_B$ energy will transfer in the form of heat from A to B  until they are in thermal equilibrium with each other at some final equilibrium temperature, $T_F$.

For conservation of energy, the energy lost by A if the form of heat = Energy gained by B in the form of heat.

$$mc(T_{A}-T_{F})=10mc(T_{F}-T_B)$$

$$T_{F}=108 C$$

Note that the final temperature of the two objects is much closer to the initial temperature of object B than object A. This is because the heat capacity of B is 10 times that of A. If the two objects had the same mass (same heat capacity), the final temperature would be the average of the initial temperatures.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clearance you gave regarding the question.I was Just trying to get the intuition behind that ,as it is generally not taught in schools(referring to my school).Just for a logical thinking ,If temperature is average kinetic energy of each particle of object so shall we conclude if two objects differ in temperature,Hence While contact they will transfer heat until each particle of the two bodies(considering the two bodies as a system) have same Kinetic energy,hence no further heat tranfer happens.I came to this conclusion,Please correct me If I am gaining a wrong intution.

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi That is essentially correct, except that not each particle of the two bodies will have the same kinetic energy, the average kinetic energy of all the particles will be the same in each body. For any temperature there is a distribution of the energies of the particles about the average. For a nice description and illustration of the transfer of kinetic energy between the bodies, check this out: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kintem.html#c1 and check this out: http://www.hyperphysics.de/hyperphysics/hbase/thermo/temper2.html#c1 So is my answer now acceptable?

Comment: Thanks a lot Respected @Bob D.My intention was not really to bother you,your answer was already acceptable.I was just trying to clear my doubts.Once again thank you

Comment: I only asked because you didn’t check off “accept”

Comment: Did you understand what I meant by check off “accept”?

Comment: What does check off mean?

Comment: It means you can accept my answer by clicking on it

Comment: silly of me, I was new to the site, didn't knew what "accepting the answer" meant at that time

Answer (score 2):

No. Heat is the transfer of thermal energy between objects that have different temperatures regardless of their conditions. Thermal energy always moves from an object with a higher temperature to an object with a lower temperature.

This is a statement of the [second law of thermodynamics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) where this law states that it is impossible for any process to have as its sole result heat transfer from a cooler to a hotter object. While from a hotter object to a cooler one, heat transfer can happen spontaneously. The natural conclusion is that for two bodies at the same temperature, no heat transfer will occur spontaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

> so in this case if both the objects are in contact ,will heat exchange
> happen

No.

Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. If there is no temperature difference between objects there can be no energy transfer in the form of heat.

I think the underlying reason for your question is not understanding the difference between heat and internal energy. The energy each of your two objects possess is its internal energy. The internal energy is the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of the molecules and atoms at the microscopic level. Heat is only the transfer of energy.

**Bottom Line:** Objects don't "possess" heat. After energy is transferred to or from an object in the form of heat, the increase or decrease in the energy of the object is no longer recognizable as heat. It is an increase or decrease in the internal energy of the object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the last three sentences

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi In order to elaborate, please be specific on what your doubt is.

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi I have posted a new answer that may perhaps better help you.

Answer (score 1):

Heat transfer is temperature based. Heat always flows from a warmer to a cooler environment. When the two objects are at the same temperature they are at equilibrium and one cannot raise or lower the temperature of the other, no matter how much or how little energy it took to raise the temperature of each individual object from 0C to 20C.

Comment: Thanks for the help